# using flutter_polyline_points 0.2.4 not working but 0.1.0 works

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

i upgraded my pub file and updated my flutter_polyline_points dependency from 0.1.0 to 0.2.4 had error saying this method accepts only 3 parameters and am making use of 5.

```
List<PointLatLng> result = await polylinePoints?.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
            googleAPIKey,
            sourceLocatioon.latitude,
            sourceLocatioon.longitude,
            destLocatioon.latitude,
            destLocatioon.longitude

        );
```

but it works in flutter_polyline_points 0.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `PointLatLng()` when passing LatLng values to the `getRouteBetweenCoordinates()` method. For example:

```
List<PointLatLng> result = await polylinePoints?.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
   googleAPIKey,
   PointLatLng(sourceLocatioon.latitude, sourceLocatioon.longitude),
   PointLatLng(destLocatioon.latitude, destLocatioon.longitude)
);
```

The new `PointLatLng` method is included in `flutter_polyline_points: 0.2.4` package that is used for passing in the origin and destination coordinates. Check the package sample [here.](https://github.com/Dammyololade/flutter_polyline_points/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart)

Comment: Thanks the package sample also helped

Comment: Glad that helped!